# how to implement color picker in java swing

Tags: java

i have used JColorChooser but look and feel is not that much great, any other way to implement color picker using java swing

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://www.etn.nl/colorpicker/) are a list of color picker applets implemented in Java (thanks to google). I know there are some other components available out there for commercial purposes.

Answer (score 3):

You might look at [*Creating a Custom Chooser Panel*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html#chooserpanel) as a way to implement your own design.

Comment: You can take ideas from the the default choosers (under their license terms of course), their class names can be retrieved from the instances you get from `colorChooser.getChooserPanels()'.

Comment: @amotzg: Good point; thanks! See also these [snippets](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12027626/230513).