# How to add transparency slider in JColorChooser with GTK look and feel

Tags: java, swing, java-7, look-and-feel, jcolorchooser

Before Java7, if you wanted to let a user choose a transparent color you had to show a `JColorChooser` and add your own transparency slider as the standard color chooser had no UI for the transparency/opacity.

As of Java7, the standard `JColorChooser` seems to include such a slider so I removed our own transparency slider. However, the `JColorChooser` when using the GTK+ look and feel lacks this slider/UI widget.

Does anybody know an easy way to add the transparency slider to the GTK+ look and feel `JColorChooser` (e.g. a system property I have to set, a key-value pair in the UI manager, ... ) ?

Looking at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12026767/1076463) I am afraid such property does not exist. Otherwise it could probably have been used to disable/remove the transparency slider.

Screenshots to illustrate what you have under Metal versus what you get under GTK:

**Metal look and feel**

[image: Metal look and feel]

**GTK+ look and feel**

[image: GTK look and feel]

**Code used to generate the screenshots**

Code must of course be run with JDK7 or higher

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.LookAndFeel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ColorChooserExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(
        new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            try {
              UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
//              UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
              JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Pick color", Color.YELLOW );
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
              throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
              throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
              throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
              throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
          }
        }
    );
  }
}
```